# Liquid Exception: Included file _includes/JB/setup not found in

Tags: jekyll

I have been using Jekyll for the past day and it has been working. I added a new file and one of my existing files began receiving the error above. I got Jekyll because it was suppose to be an easy blogging solution. This is not proving true. If I need to learn a framework just to blog I mind as well just use wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to perform `jekyll serve` from inside the **_posts/** directory.  You can only perform `jekyll serve` from the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

One of your `_layouts, post or page` use an `{% include JB/setup %}` which is supposed to work with [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/).

This `_layouts, post or page`, borrowed from Jekyll Boostrap will certainly need some variables from `JB/setup` to work as expected.